# Disable slideUp and slideDown when screen size is less than 600px

Tags: jquery, slide

I need to disable slideUp and slideDown trigger when screen size is less than 600px.
So I do not want slideUp and slideDown to be working at all when screen size is les than 600px.

I have this jQuery to creating accordion slide:

```
//ACCORDION BUTTON ACTION
jQuery(function () {
jQuery('.accordion-trigger').click(function () {
    if (jQuery(this).data("slided") === true) {
        jQuery(this).next().slideUp('normal');
        jQuery(this).data("slided", false);
    } else {
        jQuery('.accordion-trigger').data('slided', false);
        jQuery('.sec').slideUp('normal');
        jQuery(this).next().slideDown('normal');
        jQuery(this).data("slided", true);
    }
});
});
```

I have this code to check window size:

```
jQuery(window).on("load resize", function (e) {
  if (jQuery(window).width() < 600) {
  }
});
```

How to disable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
var small_screen;

jQuery(window).on("load resize", function () {
  if (jQuery(window).width() < 600) {

    small_screen = true;

  } else {

   small_screen = false;

 }

});

//ACCORDION BUTTON ACTION

    jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('.accordion-trigger').click(function () {

        if(small_screen){

             return;

        } else {

        if (jQuery(this).data("slided") === true) {
            jQuery(this).next().slideUp('normal');
            jQuery(this).data("slided", false);
        } else {
            jQuery('.accordion-trigger').data('slided', false);
            jQuery('.sec').slideUp('normal');
            jQuery(this).next().slideDown('normal');
            jQuery(this).data("slided", true);
        }

         }
    });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//ACCORDION BUTTON ACTION
jQuery(function () {
jQuery('.accordion-trigger').click(function () {
if(disableSlide) return;   
if (jQuery(this).data("slided") === true) {
        jQuery(this).next().slideUp('normal');
        jQuery(this).data("slided", false);
    } else {
        jQuery('.accordion-trigger').data('slided', false);
        jQuery('.sec').slideUp('normal');
        jQuery(this).next().slideDown('normal');
        jQuery(this).data("slided", true);
    }
});
});
var disableSlide=false;
jQuery(window).on("load resize", function (e) {
  if (jQuery(window).width() < 600) {
    disableSlide=true;
  }
  else {disableSlide=false;}
}).trigger('resize');;
```

Answer (score 0):

you could remove your check for the window size on resize, and put a request for the window height in your JQuery function.

```
//ACCORDION BUTTON ACTION
jQuery(function () {
jQuery('.accordion-trigger').click(function () {
//check window size, return if less than 600;
    if(window.innerHeight < 600) {
      return false;
    }
    if (jQuery(this).data("slided") === true) {
        jQuery(this).next().slideUp('normal');
        jQuery(this).data("slided", false);
    } else {
        jQuery('.accordion-trigger').data('slided', false);
        jQuery('.sec').slideUp('normal');
        jQuery(this).next().slideDown('normal');
        jQuery(this).data("slided", true);
    }
});
});
```